# How to convert PNG image to ZPL with labelary?

Tags: php, api, converters

I have a PNG image and i want convert to ZPL. 
After some research, I found an API to convert a ZPL to PNG / PDF.
However, can we do the opposite? The documentation only talks about converting a ZPL image and not the other way around.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution to convert PNG to ZPL ?
The ZPL documentation says about using ~DY , ~GF command directly to be able to print PNG on ZPL Printers.

Answer (score 0):

Since ZPL depends a lot on the paper format of the printer, you won't easily find a converter to ZPL And since it is proper to only one company Zebra, I doubt there'll be an open source converter in the future.